# How to get roles of users using discordjs slash commands

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I am confused about how  to get the roles of the user who interacted with the slash command

I tried

```
let roles=interaction.member.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === 'Admin');
console.log(roles)
```

It returns a whole huge object and i cant find roles

```
guild: <ref *1> Guild {
..............
.........
}
But i want all the roles that user had
```

Answer (score 0):

With `find()` alone, you would only get a role named `Admin`.

To get all roles of an user, you want to use `.map()` to map this data. This will result in an array of role objects.

```
const roles = interaction.member.roles.cache.map(role => role);
```

---

If you want to exclude a role, like `@everyone`, you can use `.filter()` to filter it out by name, id, etc.

```
const filteredRoles = roles.filter(role => role.name !== "@everyone");
```

---

You can also use it right away with `.forEach()`.

```
interaction.member.roles.cache.forEach(obj => {
    console.log(obj);
});
```

---

Your Role Object's should look like this:

(The most useful data is below the guild object as displayed below.)

```
Role {
  guild: <ref *1> Guild {
    .........
  },
  icon: null,
  unicodeEmoji: null,
  id: '1000000000000000000',
  name: 'Admin',
  color: 0,
  hoist: false,
  rawPosition: 0,
  permissions: PermissionsBitField { bitfield: 0n },
  managed: false,
  mentionable: false,
  tags: {}
}
```